# How to detect the variation of coefficients in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, temperature

I am trying to find a way to detect a hot object using Panasonic's GridEye which is a sensor that gives an 8x8 matrix with a temperature in each square.

Is there a common algorithm that allows to detect high variations in the coeffcients of my matrix? (allowing to detect very high and very low temperature objects)

In the image attached for example, I'd like to detect the red squares. The algorithm shall return "Object with temperature 28°C detected".

Temperature profile when a human enters the camera field (distance=1m)

[image: Temperature profile when a human enters the camera field (distance=1m)]

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Comment: Choose a threshold? I don't think 64 cells really allows for a whole lot of sophistication.

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to do? Try to be more formal! Maybe you want to do kernel-density estimation followed by finding-extremas (python: scipy.signal.scipy.signal.argrelextrema)? But maybe not. I also think those tags are not helping much, but i'm unable to reason about better candidates yet.